# How to write a Kusto Query in Azure that finds all what a SQL Database has spend more than 80% CPU?

Tags: azure, devops, cpu, metrics, kql

I have a problem where a particular sql database resource has spend almost 100% in some tasks which I don't know during a particular time, the main question is how to find in which tasks this resource has spend such a high amount with a Kuto Query. How would you write this?

I tried AppEvents and maybe this a solution but I can't find a feauture to fetch the cpu usage.

Comment: Is your SQL Databases running on On-Premises or Azure

Comment: Is Azure CLI works for you? @Jose Guerrero

Answer (score 1):

By referring to the [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-321-useful-kusto-monitoring-queries-for-azure-sql/ba-p/3734695#:%7E:text=AzureMetrics%20%7C%20where%20ResourceProvider%20==%20%22MICROSOFT.SQL%22%20%7C%20where,%7C%20summarize%20LOG_Write_percent%20=%20max%28Maximum%29%20by%20Resource,%20MetricName) by @Jose Manuel Jurado Diaz, I tried below kusto query that finds SQL database CPU usage.

```bash
AzureMetrics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.SQL"
| where MetricName in ('cpu_percent')
| parse _ResourceId with * "/microsoft.sql/servers/databases" Resource
| summarize CPU_percent = max(Maximum) by Resource, MetricName
```

*Note:* If you want to retrieve usage for more than `80% usage`, then filter `cpu_percent` as per your requirement.

[image]